# How to upload backup to a mini-PC

Tags: backup

I have an AceMagician Mini-PC, to which I would like to restore a 256 GB backup of a debian linux system.
How would I do this?
It only has Ethernet and USB connections, and I cannot plug in its SSD (or whatever it's using) straight to a different computer as it is sealed in the box.

EDIT: Currently the file is the file system of another AceMagician Mini-PC, but if needed I could transfer it over ssh as a .img file to my desktop pc with the `dd` utility.

Comment: What type of media is this 256GB backup on exactly? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Ok updated, it is on another mini-PC, so I suppose we want to clone that one.

Comment: You’re going to probably need external storage. Since you can’t transfer the image to the target device since you’ll be overwriting the data on the hdd. Adequate USB based storage is extremely cheap.

Answer (score -1):

1. Connect your Mini-PC to your desktop PC using the Ethernet or USB connection.
2. Use the dd utility to transfer the backup file over ssh from the other Mini-PC to your desktop PC.
3. Once the backup file is on your desktop PC, transfer it back to the Mini-PC using the same connection method.
4. Use the dd utility again to restore the backup to the Mini-PC's SSD.
5. Reboot the Mini-PC, and your Debian Linux system should be restored.